# Adding to specific position in grid layout in (java swing)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, cardlayout

```
    public static void main(String [] args) {
            
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
        
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("l1");
        panel.add(l1);
        
        frame.add(panel);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

I've created a grid-layout with 1 column and 4 rows, is there any way I can choose in which row and column to add the label? I know of the panel.add(Component, int index) variant of the add method, but idky I always get an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position" error.

Comment: Change the layout to `new GridLayout(0, 1)` and you'll be able to add one `JLabel`.  You have to specify the Swing components in the order that you want them to appear in the grid layout.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: *Why* do you feel there is a need to add components to a `GridLayout` non sequentially? See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831)

Comment: I think maybe [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could add blank components to each row (`JLabel` instances for example) and then manage what those components look like over time via their index in an array.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
JLabel rows[] = new JLabel[4];  //change ui content by managing these now

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){ 
    rows[i] = new JLabel();
    panel.add(rows[i]);
}

//Example: To modify row 3 (i.e. rows[2])
rows[2] = new JLabel("l1");

frame.add(panel);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

In this manner you would also have better access to potentially modify row dimensions.